# What is the problem with this link configuration?

Tags: cakephp

```
$html->link($article['User']['username'],array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'view_profile',$article['User']['id'],array('class' => 'button','onmouseover'=>"loadtooltip(this,'$userid')",'onmouseout'=>'hidetooltip()'))));
```

I got this problem:

[image: this]

I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One or more of the variables you are passing to the link method is an array and not a string. It's either `$article['User']['username']`, `$article['User']['id']` or `$userid`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?  $html->link($article['User']['username'],array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'view_profile',$article['User']['id']),array('class' => 'button','onmouseover'=>"loadtooltip(this,'$userid')",'onmouseout'=>'hidetooltip()'));?>
```

Check Your $html->link syntax.